# Curly brackets in latex

Tags: latex

I expect left and right curly brackets in the output of following latex code

```
H_1= \left{{h_{1},\overline {h_{1}}\right}
```

but the curly brackets do not appear

I also tried with round and square bracket and get the expected output

[image: you can see latex output with round,square and curly bracket here]

Answer (score 3):

Curly brackets have a special meaning in latex. If you want to actually print them in your code, you need to use `\{` and `\}`

Also you are opening one more bracket than you close and you must use math code inside a math environment, e.g. `$...$` or an equation.
You will get error messages in your log file and overleaf even highlights the code in red to tell you that there is an error. Never ignore error messages!

And don't abuse `\\` for line breaks. Just leave an empty line to start a new paragraph. Again, there is a warning in the log file in which latex is telling you about the underfull box caused by this. Don't ignore the feedback latex gives you!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
H_1= \left\{  h_{1},\overline{h_{1}} \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]